# Codemagic authenticate error when publishing to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, codemagic

My build on Codemagic is successful, but when the app should be deployed to App Store Connect I get the following error:

```
 {"tool-version":"4.059.1219","tool-path":"\/Applications\/Xcode-13.0.app\/Contents\/SharedFrameworks\/ContentDeliveryServices.framework\/Versions\/A\/Frameworks\/AppStoreService.framework","os-version":"11.6.1","product-errors":[{"message":"Unable to authenticate.","userInfo":{"NSLocalizedDescription":"Unable to authenticate.","NSLocalizedFailureReason":"Unable to authenticate."},"code":-19209}]}
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to upload manually after building .ipa on Codemagic and faced the same issue, so I am sure that it is caused by Apple. Even though App Manager access rights have the full permissions but it appears to be unstable.
However, Codemagic added a functionality with what publishing step will be re-run until App Store allows an app to get published which saves a lot of time. By default, retries are 10: https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/cli-tools/blob/master/docs/app-store-connect/publish.md#--altool-retriesaltool_retries_count